# I always have problem in flutter which show error in flutter library packages how to solve it

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies, android-studio-2.3

`

```
C:/Users/123/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.4.2+2/lib/src/encoder/tex/functions/frac.dart:138:37: Error: The getter 'optionsDiff' isn't defined for the class 'GreenNode'.
 - 'GreenNode' is from 'package:flutter_math_fork/src/ast/syntax_tree.dart' ('/C:/Users/123/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.4.2+2/lib/src/ast/syntax_tree.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'optionsDiff'.
      final remainingOptions = node.optionsDiff.removeStyle();
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`

i tried  to manually solve problem inside go to flutter_math_fork dependency but there are not solved.how to solve this problem i have also other dependency to same this types of error create in my flutter project whenever i build the apk.

Comment: have you tried clear cash and clear project and pub get ?

Comment: yes I tried also try to clean flutter but error always go inside the dart packages library where  i store path.